# What are the differences between webpack development and production build modes?

Tags: javascript, webpack, production-environment

In Grunt or Gulp, I used to define all the requirements myself, like: stuff should be minified only for production, livereload should be enabled only in dev server.

Webpack handles this on its own, via [its `-d` and `-p` options](https://webpack.github.io/docs/cli.html#development-shortcut-d), that toggle the loaders' `minimize` mode (most loaders ship with their relevant minifiers), the `devtool` and similar stuff (I don't know what exactly). Most of that "just works".

But on the other hand, there are some libraries that have a development and production mode. For example, React looks at `process.NODE_ENV`, and if it's `production`, it [disables the `propTypes` checking](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#installation) (which will be later stripped off by minifier as dead code, thus reducing bundle size). In Webpack, a [common way to do this is to use the `DefinePlugin`](http://ianobermiller.com/blog/2015/06/15/shave-45kb-off-your-production-webpack-react-build/).

The problem is, that this plugin should be enabled only in the production build. Some people go as far as [having 2 separate webpack configs](http://www.christianalfoni.com/articles/2015_04_19_The-ultimate-webpack-setup) because of that. This seems overkill, since most of the job is already done by webpack. I'd like to avoid this.

To find some better solution, **I'd like to understand what exactly changes** when I use the `-d` or `-p` option, and how does it affect all the loaders and plugins. I didn't find it documented anywhere. The existing documentation just mentions "debug mode" or "watch mode" without explaining what does it actually mean.

<sub>Note that I'm not asking for a do-this-and-that answer. A good, detailed explanation would be appreciated.</sub>

Answer (score 14):

## Shortcuts

Like you said, `-d` is a shortcut for `--debug --devtool source-map --output-pathinfo` where:

1. **`--debug`** activates debug mode for loaders and its behaviour depends on each loader. You can activate it via param `{ debug: true }` in your webpack.config.js
2. **`--devtool`** is basically allow to select type of sourcemaps for your files via param `{ devtool: "sourcemap" }` or if you use webpack@2: `{ devtool: 'eval-cheap-module-source-map' }`([See all options](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#devtool))
3. **`--output-pathinfo`** will write original filepath into webpack's requires like this: `__webpack_require__(/* ./src/containers/App/App.js */15)`. 
    You can activate it via: `{ output: { pathinfo: true } }`

Second shortcut, `-p` stands for `--optimize-minimize --optimize-occurence-order` where:

1. **`--optimize-minimize`** will add **webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin** into your module plugins which will minify your code (remove spaces, mangle variable names and other optimizations)
2. **`--optimize-occurence-order`** will add **webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin** to plugin list which will assign your most used dependencies lower ids, so code will be smaller.

   <sub>*For example: you have imported `react` in every file and webpack will try to require it like that `__webpack_require__(1);` instead of `__webpack_require__(1266);`*</sub>

## Putting all together

So, in your case if you have `webpack.config.js`, you can change it like this:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackConfig = {
   // here goes your base config
};

// -d shortcut analogue
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  webpackConfig.debug = true;
  webpackConfig.devtool = 'sourcemap';
  webpackConfig.output.pathinfo = true;
}

// -p shortcut analogue
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
  }));
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin());
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin());
}

module.exports = webpackConfig;
```

> If you want to look at actual parsing of these params, look at https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/bin/convert-argv.js#L19

Comment: Thank you. I have a few doubts, though: I see that [the `-p` flag sets `process.env.NODE_ENV`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/bin/convert-argv.js#L28), but how about `-d`? I also don't see `--optimize-occurence-order` in that source file.

Comment: Yeah, you right. They've removed `OccurenceOrderPlugin` for `-p` in webpack@2 and added new minimize mechanism through [`webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin`](https://git.io/vr8CG). Defining `process.env.NODE_ENV` for development is a bit overhead on processing files since it replace variables in place with strings. Also it allows you to use NODE_ENV different from 'development' so you can mock/stub something for `NODE_ENV='test'`