# How to put React in production mode?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried using the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22118915/how-to-turn-on-off-reactjs-development-mode) but the icon is still read indicating dev mode.

Here is my current file with updates from the answer below:

```
const path = require('path');
const SRC_DIR = path.join(__dirname, '/client-react/src');
const DIST_DIR = path.join(__dirname, '/client-react/dist');
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: `${SRC_DIR}/index.jsx`,
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: DIST_DIR
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({'process.env': {NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')} })
  ],
  module: {
      loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?/,
        include: SRC_DIR,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          plugins: ["transform-object-rest-spread", "transform-class-properties"],
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
       }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: What happens if you use the actual environment variable, as in `NODE_ENV=production ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js`?

Comment: It seems to be correct, can you test if **production** is set as env variable?. You can do that with `console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)` in your `index.js`

Answer (score 5):

If you use Webpack 4, you don't need to change `webpack.config.js`. It remains the same in both development and production modes.

The only thing needed is in your `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
}
```

Having this, to create a development bundle:

```
npm run dev
```

Production bundle:

```
npm run build
```

Comment: Webpack and React are different entities. So how does React know read the mode from webpack?

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me: run `npm run build` followed by `npm install -g serve` and `serve -s build`

Answer (score 2):

When you want to build your app in production mode, you should use `webpack` [production shortcut](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/cli#production-shortcut--p). Like this:

`webpack -p`

This will enable `webpack` [optimize options](https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#optimize-options) to minify your JS. See more detailed explanation of `webpack` flags [on this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37281276/6053299).

Comment: Do you have Webpack installed globally?

Comment: I think so. But if there is smth that doesn't work, you can always ask a new question :)

Answer (score 1):

Webpack plugins need to be put under the `plugins` key in `module.exports`.

https://webpack.github.io/docs/using-plugins.html#built-in-plugins

Try this:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          'process.env': { NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production') }
      }),
   ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.  You may also need to add `const webpack = require('webpack')` at the top.  Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error so to fix it I did this:

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --colors",
  "start": "NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --progress --colors"
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(env)
    })
  ]
}
```

It should work for sure.

[Here](https://github.com/arkgast/react-firebase-starter) I have some configuration that you can try to optimize your build.

Comment: The reason why you can't run webpack from your command line is because it's installed locally. If you do `npm i -g webpack` you'll be able to use it anywhere but isn't recommended.